# How to prevent Drop down option to reset to its intial once the user has choose it from the drop down

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
 $("#packID").on("change", function() {
  

  $("#packID").off('change');

  $("#text1").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));  
    }); 
    
 $("#numRowID").on("change", function() {
        $("#text2").val(this.value );
    });
```

```css
.quesTable {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.legendl {
  text-align: center;
}

packID, numRowID {
height: 30px;
}

.fRowClass {
//display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="quesTable">
  <tr style="background-color:#bcbcbc;">
   <th>Brand A</th>
    <th>Brand B</th>
    <th>This drop down selection should not reset on any event it should only get change on user selection only</th> 
    <th>This nselection should not reset on any event it should only get change on user selection only</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="legendl">Hello</td>
    <td class="legendl">Hi</td>
    <td>
    <div class="dropDownContainer">
      <select id="packID">
        <option value="">header</option>
        <option value="1">Individual</option>
        <option value="2">pack1</option>
        <option value="3">pack2</option>
        <option value="4">pack3</option>
        <option value="5">pack4</option>
        <option value="6">pack5</option>
        <option value="7">pack6</option>
        <option value="8">pack7</option>
        <option value="9">pack8</option>
        <option value="10">pack9</option>
        <option value="11">pack10</option>
        <option value="12">pack11</option>
        <option value="13">pack12</option>
        <option value="14">pack13</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </td> 
    <td>
    <div class="numberContainer">
      <input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="numRowID">

    </div>
    </td> 
  </tr>
  
</table>

   <input type="number" id="text1" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="numRowID">
   <input type="number" id="text2" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="numRowID">
 <button type="submit" id="submit1">Submit</button>
```

I have a drop down and a number container. But i don't want either of these to reset anyhow. It should only change if user is changing. Both drop down and number field is required to answer but if only drop down is selected and not number field and if press the submit button accidentally it should retain the value. Same goes for numeric field. Any help?

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#packID").on("change", function() {


        $("#packID").off('change');

        $("#text1").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });

    $("#numRowID").on("change", function() {
        $("#text2").val(this.value);
    });

    $('#submit1').click(function() {
        location.reload();
    }
```

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("#packID").on("change", function() {
  

  $("#packID").off('change');

  $("#text1").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));  
    }); 
  
 $("#numRowID").on("change", function() {
        $("#text2").val( this.value );
    });

$('#submit1').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
});
```

```css
.quesTable {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.legendl {
  text-align: center;
}

packID, numRowID {
height: 30px;
}

.fRowClass {
//display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="quesTable">
  <tr style="background-color:#bcbcbc;">
   <th>Brand A</th>
    <th>Brand B</th>
    <th>This drop down selection should not reset on any event it should only get change on user selection only</th> 
    <th>This nselection should not reset on any event it should only get change on user selection only</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="legendl">Hello</td>
    <td class="legendl">Hi</td>
    <td>
    <div class="dropDownContainer">
      <select id="packID">
        <option value="">header</option>
        <option value="1">Individual</option>
        <option value="2">pack1</option>
        <option value="3">pack2</option>
        <option value="4">pack3</option>
        <option value="5">pack4</option>
        <option value="6">pack5</option>
        <option value="7">pack6</option>
        <option value="8">pack7</option>
        <option value="9">pack8</option>
        <option value="10">pack9</option>
        <option value="11">pack10</option>
        <option value="12">pack11</option>
        <option value="13">pack12</option>
        <option value="14">pack13</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </td> 
    <td>
    <div class="numberContainer">
      <input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="numRowID">

    </div>
    </td> 
  </tr>
  
</table>

   <input type="number" id="text1" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="numRowID">
   <input type="number" id="text2" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="numRowID">
 <button type="submit" id="submit1">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Run code snippet resulted in an error. Did you included required scripts?

Comment: Yes i did, it is working fine when i run this on my PC, but showing error on Snippet ? Any help?

Comment: jquery might not be included.

Comment: @Krishnadas PC: Its updated, please check now